# Installing Pyomo and TSPLib95 with Anaconda

Tags: pip, pyomo, anaconda3

this is a rather high-level question, but I wrecked my Anaconda installation several times when pip installing the TspLib95 library [https://pypi.org/project/tsplib95/] and later installing Pyomo via conda install -c conda-forge pyomo (as recommended  here: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

So my high-level question is how to go about pip installing libraries and conda-forge installing others; is the order of installation important, resp. what can be recommended as best practices?

Comment: I think you'll live a longer, more prosperous and stress free life if you choose one or the other and stick with it.  Watching the sparks fly in virtual environments between conda, pip, homebrew, etc. can be painful.  I ditched conda a while back and solely use `pip` for everything now along with `venv` and it is painless